# How do I calculate an integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the integral $$\int_A\frac{dz}{4z^2+1},$$ where $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid|z-i|=1\}$, in the negative direction.

Comment: Define "in the negative direction."

Comment: Counterclockwise

Comment: Do you have the residue theorem?

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem or Cauchy's Integral Theorem?

Comment: I do not have the residue theorem, but I have Cauchy's integral theorem!

Comment: Counterclockwise is usally called "positive direction"

Answer (score 2):

From [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) we have

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz' \tag 1$$

where the contour $C$ is traversed counter-clockwise and $f$ is analytic in and on $C$, and $z$ is a point contained inside the region bounded by $C$.

Letting $f(z)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(z+i/2)}$, $z=i/2$, and $C$ be the contour given by $|z-i|=1$ in $(1)$, we have

$$f(i/2)=-\frac{i}{4}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{f(z')}{z'-i/2}\,dz'$$

where again, the contour is traversed counter-clockwise.

The integral of interest is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\oint_C\frac{1}{4z^2+1}\,dz=\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{f(z')}{z'-i/2}\,dz'=2\pi i \left(-\frac{i}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

and we are done!